# VBA InputBox Prompts Twice

Tags: excel, vba, prompt, inputbox

I have a simple script to require a *password* before closing a workbook (to prevent accidental closing), but the `InputBox` re-opens if I enter the correct keyword.  I have created multiple iterations of the below script, but I cannot resolve it.

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

If InputBox("Please enter the password to close the workbook.") <> "pa55word" Then
    MsgBox ("Incorrect password.  Please try again")
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
Else
    GoTo GoToClose
End If

GoToClose:
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you code it like this:

- the code simply proceeds to save the workbook if the password is correctly without a second close
- The `ThisWorkbook.Saved` at front tells Excel the workbook is fully updated so there wont be a *do you want to save* message - ie it does the same task as the `False` part of `ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False` and the existing Save event closes the workbook.

*recut*

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
If InputBox("Please enter the password to close the workbook.") <> "pa55word" Then
     MsgBox ("Incorrect password.  Please try again")
     Cancel = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  I didn't think to include the `.Saved` portion beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Events before the Close.

Comment: I have tried to do this with `Application.EnableEvents = False` but then when I re-open the document **none** of my macros execute.  I believe this only happens when I close the individual Workbook, and not the entire Excel instance, but I wanted to know if there is a better solution.